# powershell - how to map network drive on remote computer (how to run cmd commands on remote computer)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to map network drive on remote computer using Invoke-Command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock { net use L: \\server\folder password /user:login}
```

but it doesn't work. Simple NET USE doesn't work either. I've also tried [Powershell: how to map a network drive with a different username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530733/powershell-how-to-map-a-network-drive-with-a-different-username-password)

So, how to run "cmd command" NET USE on remote computer? Or how to map network drive with powershell? Thank you

**EDIT**:

When I use

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock { (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive 
("M:", "\\server\folder", $false, "login", "password") }
```

it will create some "shadow" disk that is visible only from remote computer using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock { NET USE }
```

and can be deleted by using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock { NET USE /d /y M: }
```

but I cannot see, delete or add mapped disc, that are visible when I connect to that remote server:(

Comment: *How* does it "not work"? Do you get an error? Is WinRM enabled on the remote host?

Comment: yes, winRM is enabled, i can execute commands like ipconfig and ps commands, but NET USE gives: "New connections will be remembered. There are no entries in the list."

Comment: Ansgar, when I used your command, that you've deleted already, it maps desired disc, but I can not see it on the remote machine. I can see it only when I run Invoke-command with NET USE from my computer..

Comment: I had deleted my answer, because it's the exact same solution as the accepted answer to the link you posted, which you said did not work for you. Does the command work when you change `$false` to `$true` (i.e. make the mapped drive persistent)?

Comment: No, as I wrote, I've tried advices in that link. I can add disks, remove them, display them with net use, but I cannot see them when I connect to remote computer. Then I see another disks(which were mapped locally) and anything I changed through remoce access isn't applied.

Comment: Do you log in on both computers with the same account?

Comment: Good tip, Ansgar. I have tested it, but when I map disk remotely from my computer with my account, I still can't see this disk when I connect to remote computer with the same account :( I start to think, that it's impossible do be done..

Comment: After running some tests, I can only say that it does work for me. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock {
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive(
      "L:", "\\server\share", $false, "login", "password"
    )
}
```

**Edit:** When I run the following command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerB -ScriptBlock {
  (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive(
      "L:", "\\ServerC\share", $true, "DOMAIN\UserB", "password"
    )
}
```

as `DOMAIN\UserA` on `ServerA`, it connects `\\ServerC\share` as drive `L:` on `ServerB` just fine. When I then log in on `ServerB` as `DOMAIN\UserA`, I can see the drive, but receive a warning that not all network drives could be reconnected. Which is only natural since UserA and UserB have different passwords. When I click on the drive, the system asks for the credentials of DOMAIN\UserB, and when I enter the password, I can access the share just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it using Scheduled Tasks.

**Create a standard bat file with the mapping text in it.**

`

```
net use R: /Delete /y
net use R: "\\SERVERNAME\R" /persistent:yes
net use S: /Delete /y
net use S: "\\SERVERNAME\S" /persistent:yes
```

`

**Create XML with Scheduled Taks job info**

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2016-03-12T14:19:18.8527017</Date>
    <Author>DOMAIN\USER</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers />
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <GroupId>S-1-5-32-544</GroupId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>I:\Scripts\Schedualed Taks XML\Maps.bat</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

`

**use a batch File to create Tasks (schtasks.exe)**

`

```
@echo off
if exist "exists.txt" del "exists.txt"
for /F %%A in (SNL.txt) do (

Echo %%A

schtasks.exe /create /f /tn "Map Drives" /XML "I:\Scripts\Schedualed Taks XML\DriveMaps.xml" /s %%A


)
pause
```

`

**NOTE:** SNL.txt is a list of computers you wish to crate the task on.

**Then use a batch file to run the task** (you could make this one Batch file if you want)

`

```
@echo off
if exist "exists.txt" del "exists.txt"
for /F %%A in (SNL.txt) do (

Echo %%A

schtasks.exe /run /s %%A /tn "Map Drives" 

)

Pause
```

`

Answer (score 0):

According to [This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/78402965-0ba2-41d6-9eeb-9044c916efa1/powershell-mapremove-networkdrives-on-remote-computer?forum=ITCG) article it's not possible without CredSSP?
I'm trying to do the same thing =(