# Powershell - WinRM - Map a drive with remote credentials

Tags: networking, powershell, drive, winrm

Is there a way to use WinRM to map a drive on a remote machine with the credentials of the session logged in on that remote machine, WITHOUT prompting the user to input their credentials.

Edit: This machine is on an AD domain, so ideally using the existing auth ticket would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) on how to run PS commands remotely, then [Powershell: how to map a network drive with a different username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530733/powershell-how-to-map-a-network-drive-with-a-different-username-password) on the specific command you need.