# Cannot see mapped drive in File Explorer

Tags: powershell

Mapped network drive with

```
New-PsDrive -Name Z -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\localhost\C$\Users\Keith\Documents\Project" -Persist
```

In cmd and powershell I can navigate to Z:\, but the drive does not appear in file explorer and I cannot navigate to the drive in file explorer.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

PSDrive isn't intended for this purpose.

You can use a simple cmd era solution:

```
net use Z: "\\localhost\C$\Users\Keith\Documents\Project" /persistent:yes
```

A COM and PS solution:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("Z:", "\\localhost\C$\Users\Keith\Documents\Project")
```

You can check here for further details: [Powershell: how to map a network drive with a different username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530733/powershell-how-to-map-a-network-drive-with-a-different-username-password)

Comment: OP specifically aske to do this in powershell, so running a command in/via CMD is *cheating*. There must be a good solution for using pwsh. The MS documents for these commands are simply not showing reality.

Answer (score 0):

when you run the command in an elevated powershell (as administrator) your user account logged on does not see the drive. but if you run a "normal" powershell and run the command there the drive is displayed as expected. make sure you use the correct user account.